# How to support for Windows SBS 2011 OS in InstallShield installer?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2015, windows-sbs

I have an MSI installer built in InstallShield 2015. I want to support my MSI installer for OS Windows SBS 2011. But there is no provision of this OS condition in InstallShield 2015. How to add support of this OS in MSI installer in IS 2015 ?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the installer on Windows SBS 2011? Any error message or misbehaviour?

Comment: I'm getting an error message as "installation does not run on this operating system version..."